# SQL Select only month from YYYYMMDD int format

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am currently trying to write a script that will show the number of sales an employee made for each month by looking at the TransactionDate column (YYYYMMDD int).  I tried using a CAST LEFT approach to look only at the YYYYMM part of the TransactionDate but I am still getting duplicate sales person names with individual counts for each of the days they made a sale for that particular month.  What would the best approach be for simply getting an individuals total number of sales for a month, instead of showing their name and count for each day of that month?  Is this something that needs to be addressed in the script or can it be fixed in the SSRS report matrix?

```
select s.FirstName + s.LastName as 'Sales Person',
    s.DepartmentID as 'Department ID',
    count(fact.EmpID),
    CAST(LEFT(CAST(fact.TransactionDateKey AS VARCHAR(100)), 6) AS INT)
from Final.DimSalesPerson s
    inner join Final.FactRxTransactionDay fact
        on fact.EmpID = s.EmpID
where fact.TransactionDateKey between 20161101 and 20161229
group by s.FirstName + s.LastName,
    s.DepartmentID,
    fact.TransactionDateKey
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group by `CAST(LEFT(CAST(fact.TransactionDateKey AS VARCHAR(100)), 6) AS INT)` instead of `fact.TransactionDateKey`.

```
select s.FirstName + s.LastName as 'Sales Person',
    s.DepartmentID as 'Department ID',
    count(fact.EmpID),
    CAST(LEFT(CAST(fact.TransactionDateKey AS VARCHAR(100)), 6) AS INT)
from Final.DimSalesPerson s
    inner join Final.FactRxTransactionDay fact
        on fact.EmpID = s.EmpID
where fact.TransactionDateKey between 20161101 and 20161229
group by s.FirstName + s.LastName,
    s.DepartmentID,
    CAST(LEFT(CAST(fact.TransactionDateKey AS VARCHAR(100)), 6) AS INT)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another option is TransactionDate/100 it will return YYYYMM from a YYYYMMDD int.

```
Select s.FirstName + s.LastName as 'Sales Person',
    s.DepartmentID as 'Department ID',
    count(fact.EmpID),
    fact.TransactionDateKey/100 as 'Period'
from Final.DimSalesPerson s
    inner join Final.FactRxTransactionDay fact
        on fact.EmpID = s.EmpID
where fact.TransactionDateKey between 20161101 and 20161229
group by s.FirstName + s.LastName,
    s.DepartmentID,
    fact.TransactionDateKey/100
```